# Performing string functions on columns in a SQL Server statement using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a SQL statement which - trimmed down for this question - looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN SMS_Blacklist ON Customers.MobileNumber = SMS_Blacklist.Mobile_Number
WHERE SMS_Blacklist.Mobile_Number IS NULL
```

This works for the most part however the database has no data continuity or consistency and when the data looks like this:

- Customer.MobileNumber = "07123 456789",
- SMS_Blacklist.Mobile_Number = "07123456789"

it returns the record when it shouldn't (because the phone numbers don't match).

My question is, is it possible to perform a string function (i.e. `string.replace(" ", "")`) in the middle of the SQL statement so it might look something like this (I think probably not):

```
...
ON (Customers.MobileNumber).replace(" ","") = SMS_Blacklist.Mobile_Number
...
```

or how could I achieve something like this?

I am creating the SQL statement using `new SqlCommand()` in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rectifying phone numbers is very tricky.  But if you just want to remove spaces and hyphens you can do `replace()` in the SQL:

```
SELECT c.
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     SMS_Blacklist b
     ON b.Mobile_Number = REPLACE(REPLACE(c.MobileNumber, ' ', ''), '-', '')
WHERE b.Mobile_Number IS NULL;
```